# Generate random index different then any one given in a set

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I would like to generate an index from `0` to `size - 1`, uniformly, but different than any index in the given set `excluded`.

`size` is around 100. There are typically 1, 2 or 3 `exluded` indices. Indices in `excluded` are unique and not sorted.

Ideally, the header will be with multiple arguments, maybe something like this:

```
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int... i)
```

Or, if this `...` multi arguments are slow (are they?) we can pass simple `int[] excluded` array or something.

How to do it fast? `getRandomIndex()` is called millions of times.

Comment: So you want to generate a random number with the constraint that it is not contained in some set of numbers?

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JamesMontagne And inferior than size.

Comment: You could add all valid index in a collection and then pickup a random element from this set. Of course, it would be not efficient if the number of valid index is huge.

Comment: If you care about building an array then build a `Set` instead!

Comment: @A4L `Set` for 1, 2 or 3 values...? I think it's a performance killer.

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it is workable for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, Integer... excludes) {
    List<Integer> excludeList = Arrays.asList(excludes);
    int number;
    do {
        number = rand.nextInt(size);
    } while (excludeList.contains(number));

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate array of possible values 0..size-1, remove all known indexes and select random element from the rest.

If indexes array is sorted and all values are unique, you can do it without intermediate array of values :

```
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int... ii)
{
  int result = rand.nextInt(size - ii.length);
  for(int i : ii) {
    if(result >= i) {
      ++result; 
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Edit: I found mistake in if condition, corrected.

**EDIT:**

```
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int i) {
  int result = rand.nextInt(size - 1);
  if(result >= i) {
    result++;
  }
}

int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int i, int j) {
  int result = rand.nextInt(size - 2);
  if(i > j) {
    int tmp = j;
    j = i;
    i = tmp;
  }
  if(result >= i) {
    result++;
  }
  if(result >= j) {
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

And similar function for (i,j,k).

A function that call `rand.next` only one time might be faster of any function, that asks for random number several times.

Comment: use `rand.nextInt(size - ii.length)` instead of `rand.nextInt() % (size - ii.length)` or the result will not be uniformly distributed (especially if size is large)

Comment: Uniqueness is very good, you can simply add `Arrays.sort` call as first statement of `getRandomIndex`.

Comment: @Nikolay: You solution gives double probability to the elements following the excluded ones. And if you exclude 1 and 2, then the probability of 3 triples.

Comment: @maaartinus: Let's check. size == 4, 1,2 are excluded. `rand.nextInt(size - 2)` can yield 0 or 1, 0 stays unmodified, 1 changes to 3. Probability is 1/2 for both values.

Comment: @Nikolay: But if you exclude 0 and 1, then you always get 2.

Comment: @Nikolay: +1 and apologies... I've misread the code (asuming you're using `==`). Actually, with `>=` it's pretty smart.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it a bit differently.  To pick a random number less than size but which isn't i or j, you can pick a random number between 0 and size-3 inclusive.  If that number is i then return size-2 and if the number is j then return size-1.  Otherwise return the original random number.

There is the edge case of i or j being within 2 of size, but I leave that to the interested reader. Actually I think it just works out OK.

This can be generalized to pick a number less than size that isn't in an array of integers.  Choose a number less than size - the array length - 1.

Comment: I got it. I think it is best solution. Code is very simple
`int result = rand.nextInt(size - ii.length) 
 for(int i = 0; i < ii.length; ++i) {
  if(ii[i] == result) return size - i - 1;
} return result;`

Comment: @Nikolay Doesn't work for `getRandomIndex(random, 5, 1,2,4)` (generates `0` and `4` instead of `0` and `3`).

Comment: Yes. There is a trouble. Permutations between excluded indexes and tail may be coupled like your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Set` fro fast look up

```
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, Integer... i) {
    return getRandomIndex(rand, size, new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(i)));
}


int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, Set<Integer> x) {
    int result;
    do {
        result = (int) (rand.nextDouble() * size);
    } while (x.contains(result));
    return result;
}
```

If the set of all indices is predefined then you could have the `Set` `x`  `final static` and spare building it every time you call the method.

**EIDT**

Well If performance is an issue then I would say that your first approach with `while(r == i || r == j || r == k)` is neither bad nor ugly, just have three overloads of your method and call the appropriate one you need, the call will look exactly the same as with a val-len-array.

You can't have an evaluation faster than `(r == i || r == j || r == k)`

```
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int i)
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int i, int j)
int getRandomIndex(Random rand, int size, int i, int j, int k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming many consecutive calls uses the same size and excluded values...

- First, initializing an array of all the allowable indices
- When `getRandomIndex` is called, simply pick a random element of this array

Code:

```
int[] indices;

void init(int size, Integer... excluded)
{
   indices = new int[size-excluded.length];
   int pos = 0;
   Set<Integer> excludedSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(excluded));
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      if (!excludedSet.contains(i))
      {
         indices[pos++] = i;
      }
   }
}

int getRandomIndex(Random random)
{
   return indices[random.nextInt(data.length)];
}
```

Example usage:

```
init(100, 50, 23, 10);
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
   System.out.println(getRandomIndex(random));
}
```