# How can I generate two random numbers(not repeated)?

Tags: java, random

I want to generate two numbers in range 0..99 in java and it has to be not repeated. I tried code below but it is not working for me.

```
    int number1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    int number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

    if(number1 == number2){
        while (number1 != number2){
            number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: while (number1 != number2) - shouldnt be there == ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `number1` and `number2` are equal, they will not be **not** equal. Just change your `while` loop:

```
int number1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
int number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

while(number1 == number2){
    number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you never enter your loop, because the condition is wrong. In the loop, you want `==`, not `!=`. You can also remove the `if`:

```
int number1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
int number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

while (number1 == number2){
    number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
int number2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(99);
if(number2 >= number1) {
  ++number2;
}
```

Also check discussion about it at [Generate random index different then any one given in a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743858/generate-random-index-different-then-any-one-given-in-a-set/19743961#comment29351147_19743961)

Answer (score 0):

If they all have to be unique, you should add the results to a list. Then, you can compare the current random number to each of the past results.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int number1 = random.nextInt(100);
    int number2 = random.nextInt(100);
    List<Integer> randomsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (randomsList.contains(number1)){
        number1 = random.nextInt(100);
    }
    randomsList.add(number1);

    while (randomsList.contains(number2)){
        number2 = random.nextInt(100);
    }
    randomsList.add(number2);
```